# Trying to swap two strings using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
my favorite berry is the blueberry, not the strawberry or berryfruit
```

I want to find all instances of `berry` and `blueberry` where each is an isolated word, as opposed to a substring of a longer word, and change each into the other, to get this result:

```
my favorite blueberry is the berry, not the strawberry or berryfruit
```

Naturally, I can't just do this:

```
str=str.replace(/blueberry/g,"berry");
str=str.replace(/berry/g,"blueberry");
```

because that will just change all the "berry" substrings to "blueberry".

I've tried the following code:

```
<div id="displayDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function replaceSeparateInstances(inputStr,findStr,replaceStr){

        var re=new RegExp("^"+findStr+"(?!\w)|^"+findStr+"$|[\\W\\s]"+
                    findStr+"(?!\w)|[\\W\\s]"+findStr+"$","g");

        return inputStr.replace(re,replaceStr);
    }

    function berryBlueberrySwap(inputStr){
        var result=replaceSeparateInstances(inputStr,"blueberry","abc");
        result=replaceSeparateInstances(result,"berry","xyz");      
        result=result.replace(/abc/g,"berry");
        result=result.replace(/xyz/g,"blueberry");
        return result;

    }

    var div=document.getElementById("displayDiv");
    var content="my favorite berry is the blueberry, not the strawberry or berryfruit";
    div.textContent=berryBlueberrySwap(content);
</script>
```

There are several problems with this:

- The spaces are being removed from the left of words replaced by `replaceSeparateInstances()` because there's no negative lookbehind in Javascript.  I've seen some of the SO posts on how to do a workaround for this but I can't figure out how to apply them for purposes of a `replace()`.
- This solution relies on changing the two strings into temp strings "abc" and "xyz", which is a problem if these strings actually exist in the text.
- The "berry" in "berryfruit" is getting found by the regex, and it shouldn't be found because the "f" to the right of "berry" is a `\w` character.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: I tried using the function described at the duplicate link, as follows:

```
function switchInstances(inputStr,findStr1,findStr2){

        var findStr="("+findStr1+"|"+findStr2+")";

        var re=new RegExp("^"+findStr+"(?!\w)|^"+findStr+"$|[\\W\\s]"+
                    findStr+"(?!\w)|[\\W\\s]"+findStr+"$","g");
        console.log(re.source);

        return inputStr.replace(re,function($1){
            return $1===findStr1 ? findStr2 : findStr1});
    }

function berryBlueberrySwap(inputStr){

        var result=switchInstances(inputStr,"berry","blueberry");
        return result;      

 }
```

But that generated this output:

```
my favoriteberry is theberry, not the strawberry orberryfruit
```

So I still have the problem of the lookbehinds, and now the "berry" isn't being changed into "blueberry".

Comment: you can try using `\b+findstr+\b|\b+findstr2+\b`

Comment: @vks that worked.  If you post something like that, I will accept it.